# Trying to understand apple's status code definition

Tags: ios

I came across this status code `21006` on [Apple's status code page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/status) and it says

> This receipt is valid but the subscription has expired. When this
>   status code is returned to your server, the receipt data is also
>   decoded and returned as part of the response. Only returned for iOS
>   6-style transaction receipts for auto-renewable subscriptions.

The last sentence there is confusing for me. **Does this mean it will be returned for iOS versions 6 and after? or only iOS version 6?**

**Can I safely use this code to assume a subscription has expired?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can receive iOS 6 style receipts in later iOS versions. At first glance it seems to depend on how you fetch your receipt.  When I look at this [developer forums thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/97404), `appStoreReceiptURL` in your main bundle should be iOS 7 style.

[If you're validating a receipt, look in the response JSON](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html) for `latest_expired_receipt_info` and if it exists, you're dealing with iOS 6 style.